# Clarifying the usage of (path-length) tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [path-length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-length) was created about two months ago in the question: [Prove that there exists an another path $g$ with the same image as $f$ but length of $g = tL \forall t\in [0,1]$ where $L$ is the length of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2696001). Although it [has been later removed](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2696001/revisions) from this specific question, it was added to [several other questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/5/23).

It seems that some of these questions use the word length in the sense "[length of a curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)". However, there already exists a tag with this meaning, namely [arc-length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arc-length). (And this tag exists for some time. You can find it in questions from 2015 and [the taxonomist badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=131577) for this tag was awarded in 2016.) Some of these new question use this term in *graph-theoretic sense,* i.e., they are questions about length of a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) in a graph.

The [tag-info for path-length](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/path-length/info) is currently empty.

What should be done about the new tag? Is it useful to have a separate tag for length of a path in a graph? (If yes, that we should explicitly explain that the new tag is for these questions and mention the tag (arc-length) in the tag-wiki as the correct tag for the other meaning of the word length.)

Comment: I am a noob in graph theory, but if a similar tag is needed, we have to make clear that it is not something used in Riemannian geometry/metric geometry.

Comment: @JohnMa I will add that there is also ([tag:geodesic]), which seems related to these areas. Do you think that possibly (arc-length) might be suitable also for questions about length from areas you've mentioned? I see 20 questions tagged [arc-length+differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arc-length+differential-geometry). There are also 4 questions tagged [arc-length+riemannian-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arc-length+riemannian-geometry). So perhaps the tag is being used also for those meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would vote to remove this tag. It is awfully specific; I'm not sure why we would need to have a special tag for (graph-theory) problems concerning path length. Especially since about 90% (anything about finding shortest path) would be covered by adding the (optimization) tag.

Comment: The voting so far is decidedly in favor of removal of the tag. So I have accepted the answer (and removed the tag from the existing questions).

Answer (score -2):

Posting a possible proposal so that we can discuss in the comments (or at least show by voting) whether this would be the way to go.

The tag [path-length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-length) could remain, and it could be used for questions concerning length of a path in the *graph-theoretic sense*. This should be clearly explained in the tag-info. The tag-excerpt could be something like:

> Tag for questions about length of the path in a graph and various results and algorithms related to this notion. Use together with (graph-theory) tag. If your question is actually about length of a curve, then the appropriate tag is (arc-length).

In the tag-wiki the tag could be described in more detail. For example, some algorithms which would fall under this tag could be mentioned (for example, [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and similar algorithms). I suppose that having a separate tag for each of these algorithms would be too specific.

Comment: I kind of hoped that somebody would post some suggestion what to do with the tag in an answer. (Especially knowing the opinion of users who are [active in graph-theory tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/graph-theory/topusers) woudl be useful.) Since some time passed without much feedback, I posted an answer myself. If you consider this tag to be too specific, please say so here in comments (or simply downvote the proposal).

Comment: If [tag:graph-theory] isn't specific enough, and with a whole week's questions showing on the first page I think it probably is, then [tag:graph-algorithms] surely is.

Comment: Just to clarify what you mean @PeterTaylor - you're suggesting to create a new tag ([tag:graph-algorithms])?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that *if* a more specific tag within graph theory were necessary (which I don't think it is) *then* [tag:graph-algorithms] would be preferable to [tag:path-length].

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, at least now understand what you mean. A new tag (graph-algorithm) maybe might be reasonable, since [graph algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Graph_algorithms) are indeed quite a big topic. They include many other topics, not only algorithms related to path lengths. (In case you reconsider and you decide to propose such tag, maybe you could make a post about it - I am not sure whether it is better to go with a separate question or to make a post in the tag management thread.)